# how to use Intel PT to get assembly code of a target process in real time

Tags: real-time, intel, trace

I try to get assembly code of a target process in real time so that I can analysis the feature of the process. I find Intel PT can trace Instruction.But I don't know how to achive this

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do, on what OS?  Are you on a light-weight real-time OS that doesn't have profiling features (like Linux `perf`) built-in?  Under most OSes, you will need OS support to look inside another process.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573903/can-intel-pt-processor-trace-be-disabled-configured-from-within-an-os for using Intel PT under Linux

Comment: Dump the process memory.

Answer (score 1):

Intel PT just gives you program flow information, e.g. if an if-branch has been taken, at which address an interrupt occurred, etc.
This information needs to be combined with the assembly code of the executed binary. Once you have done this, you get the assembly code, that has been executed, in real-time.